# Python value assignment does not print

Tags: python, concatenation

I'm a student and have a question. I'm not getting the correct output in our textbook.

```
first = 'I'
second = 'love'
third = 'Python'
sentence = first + '' + second + '' + third + '.'
```

Output:

```
I love Python.
```

When I run it, nothing happens. Can someone explain why? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint: If you don't [`print` anything](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html), nothing gets printed.  If you're using a [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read–eval–print_loop) you might see intermediate output.

Comment: Huh. In the old days, when a question was asked that wouldn't be helpful to anyone but the OP, we had a "too localized" close reason. This seems fairly equivalent -- at least, maybe it should be retitled to "Why doesn't a Python assignment print any output?" or such, to actually have a title specific to the question, and applicable to people who don't have the OP's specific textbook.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy It is a perfectly valid question. You don't need the textbook, the source code is provided that is being used. If you want to retitle the question, do. It is helpful to any begginer in python who has been using individual commands in shell and is moving on to an actual program.

Comment: @ArtemisFowl, a question is only helpful to someone who can find it. Nobody is going to search for "not getting output in my textbook", and if they do, this'll be lost amongst hundreds of other, completely unrelated questions about code emitting the wrong output for completely unrelated reasons -- which is why it should be, at minimum, retitled.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy so edit the title

Comment: @ArtemisFowl, letting someone fix a mistake themselves reduces their changes of making it again -- which is why I suggested an appropriate title above, with an explanation of reasoning behind the change.

Comment: Thank you, I understood my error now. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

`print sentence`. Will print the outut

But from what you have this will output `"IlovePython."` not `I love Python.`

This is because ther is no space between your `''` tags. To fix this convert all those `''` to `' '`. Save the last one, which is `.` as it should be.

Comment: This works in python2.  Python3 requires: `print(sentence)`

Answer (score 0):

Your sentence variable should be:

```
sentence = first + ' ' + second + ' ' + third + '.'
```

and after assigning the value to `sentence` you have to print it:

```
print (sentence)
```

Also you can print directly the concatenation without saving it into a variable:

```
print (first + ' ' + second + ' ' + third + '.')
```